# kubenrates (k8s) nd POD OOMKILLED during not working hours and no memory spikes

Tags: kubernetes, out-of-memory, grafana

This is the situation,
first time on AWS, first time on K8s...
we have a microservice infrastructure,
we have memory issue with pods/container with jdk8 so we move to jdk11-openj9
memory management if far way well than before, the issue now is a strange one,
a microservice, that is working fine with the assigned memory, get OOMKILL during the not working hours, at random hours, today ar 5.03 AM
this POD is configured to have a QOS = GUARANTEED and this is the only one so EVICTION is not what is happening.
We monitored (with grafana) also the other PODS in that NODE and at the killing time, no one has a memory spike

bitly (the one killed): [scrennshot from grafana][image: https://i.imgur.com/zphWYkr.png]

config: [scrennshot from grafana][image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MKoY.png]

oauth2: [scrennshot from grafana][image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNUQN.png]

redis: [scrennshot from grafana][image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xLz1.png]

customactivity: [scrennshot from grafana][image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSX9q.png]

chat: [scrennshot from grafana][image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0PFn.png]

someone have a suggestion where to look?

OOMKILLED sure not for memory excessive request in my opinion.

update 15/05/2020

killed again this morning :
State:          Running
Started:      Fri, 15 May 2020 01:11:27 +0000
Last State:     Terminated
Reason:       OOMKilled
Exit Code:    137
Started:      Wed, 13 May 2020 07:32:46 +0000
Finished:     Fri, 15 May 2020 01:11:27 +0000
Ready:          True
Restart Count:  1
Limits:
memory:  250Mi
Requests:
cpu:        100m
memory:     250Mi

no reason why OOMKILLED, no memory peak or system overload

Comment: Look at the system log. It will have info about the system state when oomkiller activated.

Comment: done , but no info on why OOMKILLED.  today not occurred again, it's really strange

Comment: this morning agai nOOMKILLED

Comment: As far as I know OOM kill due to container limit reached, The exit code 137 is important because it means that the system terminated the container as it tried to use more memory than its limit. As you have provided in the update there is memory limit for 250Mi and cpu for 100m, maybe that's not enough for your application?  Have you tried to increase the amount of memory?

Comment: yes i tried to increas to 300Mi but same situation, if th memory limit was exceded, grafana wil lreport me the level of used memory but as you can see, the memory used is always the same.

Comment: Hi Sminervini. How did you eventually fix this oomkilled issue? I ran into the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The limits memory isnt the same with JVM's memory. It should be larger than that. You can use JVM parameter MaxRAMPercentage or Xmx to spare memory for the part non-heap.

See also https://akobor.me/posts/heap-size-and-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-for-jvm-applications